# replace string in json file with contents of another text file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

i'm trying to use sed to replace the string "temp" inside text.json with the contents of anotherfile.txt,

so far I have :

```
sed -e '/"temp"/{r anotherfile.txt' -e 'd;}' ./text.json >  $tmp && mv $tmp ./text.json
```

however this replaces the entire line, I only want to replace the string.

Comment: Can you provide test case of `text.json`, `anotherfile.txt` and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(somecommand)` to use a commands output in your command. Note that you cannot use single quotes `'` as they would prevent shell expansion.

#### Example:

```
╰─$ echo "some text here" > foo
╰─$ echo "some other text" > bar
╰─$ cat foo && cat bar                
some text here
some other text
╰─$ sed -e "s/text/$(cat bar)/g" foo                                                                                                                                     
some some other text here
```